# Склонение городом на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте
Существуют ли скрипты по склонению (не по падежам) название городом?
К примеру:
Москва  (куда)  в Москву.
Москва  (откуда) из Москвы.

Спасибо.

Comment: [http://morpher.ru/](), сейчас правда висит почему-то

Comment: Напомнило:

> И.П.: когда
> Р.П.: когды
> Д.П.: когде
> В.П.: когду
> Т.П.: когдой
> П.П.: на когде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/demo

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это то, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

[Яндекс.Склонятор](http://habrahabr.ru/post/39327/)

Comment: Этот проект уже тыщу лет как закрыт, как и все nano.yandex.ru.

Answer (score 0):

Хоть и через 3 года, но решение теперь есть - https://github.com/wapmorgan/Morphos

Без словарей, без сторонних сервисов. Имена, города, слова, числа.